# Use Webcam in 12.10 from Hyper-V

Tags: 12.10, windows-8, virtualization, webcam, hyper-v

I just installed 12.10 on Windows 8 Hyper-V because I have a task which needs Windows and Ubuntu simultaneously (even though I have Ubuntu dual-booted).

I need to use the webcam from Hyper-V and am unable to make Ubuntu recognise it. Cheese just shows a black screen. This is an urgent matter.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyper-V doesn't support USB devices and also the Linux support given by Microsoft for Hyper-V doesn't include the Ubuntu distribution. Hence, I feel there is no way under Hyper-V. I used VirtualBox for the same purpose.

Also, I would suggest VMware if possible as it is more stable (especially in Windows 8 in which VBox is pretty unusable for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing the device through your system:

1. Start at the Ubuntu end with any tools that can detect the webcam. Look for it in the output of **lsusb** (from usbutils) or just examine the output of  **dmesg |grep -i usb**

   *I'm only guessing your webcam is USB*
2. Next check the Windows end, used the device manager or other utilities to determine if the webcam is detectable.
3. Finally check Hyper-V. You may need to enable the device in Hyper-V.  I've never used Hyper-V, but I imagine it has facilities for sharing hardware that may need to be configured.

Comment: video on USB use with Hyper-V http://vimeo.com/7939558

Comment: It is an integrated webcam. Windows detects it perfectly (it is the host). Ubuntu doesn't